# How to backup and restore a VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox

I have just started to use VirtualBox, as this is a great way of doing linux experiments. My laptop runs Windows. However, for this to be simple, there are two things which would be nice to have:

1) The ability to scratch a VM, or alternatively store the configuration (the second option would be preferred, as I then will be able to use it in a similar way to the OpenStack flavors). The main goal, with this bullet, is to be able to start a new VM withoug having to reconfigure the actual VM properties beforehand. This is just annoying (especially, since it is possible to define some VM properties working with a lot of different use cases).

2) A way to backup and restore a VM to a specific state. This way I will be able to create a base image, and everytime I fail, I can restore it to a previous state. I assume I have to delete the current VM in this state and create a new VM based on the backup vdi in this case.

Anyone who knows if this have support in VirtualBox?

BR
Patrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With snapshots, you can save a particular state of a virtual machine for later use. At any later time, you can revert to that state, even
>   though you may have changed the VM considerably since then. A snapshot
>   of a virtual machine is thus similar to a machine in Saved state, but
>   there can be many of them, and these saved states are preserved.
>
> To see the snapshots of a virtual machine, click on the machine name
>   in VirtualBox Manager. Then click the List icon next to the machine
>   name, and select Snapshots. Until you take a snapshot of the machine,
>   the list of snapshots will be empty except for the Current State item,
>   which represents the "now" point in the lifetime of the virtual
>   machine.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots